# Trying to download a list of movies

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a list of movie titles, dates and length from this website http://www.fancast.com/movies The code that I have is:

```
// used to build entire input
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // used on each read operation
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        // prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://www.fancast.com/movies");

        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();

        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            // make sure we read some data
            if (count != 0)
            {
                // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                // continue building the string
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
```

which is borrowed from some sample code I found on the net. However, when I look at what it downloaded, it does not contain the information I am looking for. It has the same information that the website's "View Source" has. It appears it is making a call to another site that has the info but I can't seem to find or access it. Any help on how to grab a list of movie titles, length and/or date would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not that it helps you with your question, but you can replace all that code with `string pageData = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.fancast.com/movies");`

Comment: But what is your real question? Do you want to extract some data from the downloaded page? In that case, do that view source-trick and paste a chunk of data that contains the information you need and point out what parts you want to extract from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, If you analyze the source code of that webpage you'll see that the movies are loaded from another URL.
Use google chrome developer tools (or any other tool like "Fiddler2 which i really recommend)  to trace all the resources downloaded by the browser when displaying the web page.

I did it, seems like the movie database is grabbed from: http://www.fancast.com/movies_free_db.widget

So, change the WebRequest to point to that url.

Comment: Done :). I have been playing around with google chrome developer tools and am still curious how you discovered that the movie title info was on http://www.fancast.com/movies_free_db.widget. Also, do you know where I can find movie length and release year? Sorry, I am very new at this and have been poking around the source code of the webpage to no luck :(

Comment: Open new tab. Click on Tools->Developer Tools.  Click on resources -> Enable resource tracking.  Watch the timeline, it shows which content was downloaded while fetching the page.    
You will see 1) a file called movies_free_db.widget (the DB keyword called my atention)  2) all the movie images are downloaded after the DB... so, it seemed pretty clear...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...there's a fairly large can of worms that you have opened up there.

Your comment that the result, "...contains the same info as View Source...," makes me think that you don't fully understand the details of what is going on.

I recommend [HTTP Programming Recipes for C#](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/series/20). That is the book I read when I first wrote a web spider, and I think it will give you a good push in the right direction.